# Read specific place from XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, imdb

So I have an XML file and it gets information from imdb which is like that,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root response="True">
    <movie title="Game of Thrones" year="2011–" rated="TV-MA" released="17 Apr 2011" runtime="56 min" genre="Adventure, Drama, Fantasy" director="N/A" writer="David Benioff, D.B. Weiss" actors="Peter Dinklage, Lena Headey, Emilia Clarke, Kit Harington" plot="Several noble families fight for control of the mythical land of Westeros." language="English" country="USA" awards="Won 1 Golden Globe. Another 133 wins &amp; 248 nominations." poster="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTgxOTI4NzY2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjY3MTM2NDE@._V1_SX300.jpg" metascore="N/A" imdbRating="9.5" imdbVotes="868,876" imdbID="tt0944947" type="series"/>
</root>
```

I wanna get a specific attribute which is `imdbRating` I've looked so many parse questions from this site and I still couldn't figured it out best solution I come up with is,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("game of thrones.xml");
string var = doc.Descendants("movie title").Attributes("imdbRating").FirstOrDefault().Value;
labelImdb.Content = var;
```

but it does give me an error in this line

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("game of thrones.xml");
```

I also tried that and didn't work either

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("game of thrones.xml");
string dummy = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("imdbRating").InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(dummy);
Console.ReadLine();
```

second one gives an error in this line,

```
xml.LoadXml("game of thrones.xml");
```

error is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Please include the exact errors you see

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting the `movie` node incorrectly.

```
var xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\YourFile.xml"); //or from service

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var rating = xDoc.Descendants("movie").First().Attribute("imdbRating").Value;
```

The node you need to select is *`movie`*, not *`movie title!`*

But, it should not throw error at `XDocument.Parse`. Check your `XML` once again, I tried with your sample `XML` and it worked just fine. Make sure there's no empty space at beginning of file.

Answer (score 0):

Both `XDocument.Parse` and `XmlDocument.LoadXml` expect their parameter to be the string which contains the xml, not a string containing a file name. You want to use `XmlDocument.Load`, which accepts a filename:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("game of thrones.xml");
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name. It gives me that error when i use XDocument.Load

Comment: Apparently XDocument doesn't like spaces in the file name. I'll edit the answer to use XmlDocument